# When .join is not allowed, how to add commas in string Python

Tags: python

PYTHON code

```
def __str__(self):
    return_string = ""
    return return_string

    '''Return string with all items from the array
    Have a comma and a space between them
    but no brackets ([ ]) around them'''
```

Does anyone have a way of doing this without using .join, .append or formatting :) ?

Comment: you can just loop over the array and concatenate all its elements to a string

Comment: You can convert the array to string using `str()` then trim `[` and `]`

Comment: And why is join not available?

Comment: There is no `join is not allowed`, you just need to convert each to a string

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you mean an `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, XXX found` when you  say *join is not allowed*.

To fix that, convert each element to a string, either with `map`, or a generator

```
values = [0, 1, 2, 3]
result = ", ".join(map(str, values))       # map
result = ", ".join(str(v) for v in values) # generator

# 0, 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do so without using .join;

```
arr = [your_items_here]
new_str = ''

for i in range(len(arr)):
    new_str += f'{arr[i]},'

print(new_str)
```